# How to use Manage Metedata Taxonomy as a Source for Dropdown box in Infopath

Tags: 2013, infopath, managed-metadata, taxonomy, guid

I have an InfoPath form with a dropdown box, where I want users to be able to select which department they work in. Department details are stored in Managed Metadata :

`Managed Metadata Service -> People -> Department -> [...]`

I have managed to connect to the taxonomy service in PowerShell with this code, so I know which GUIDs I need to use :

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell

# Get the site collection
$sitecollection = Get-SPSite 'http://mysharepointsite/'

# Get the term store id
$taxsession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $sitecollection

# Change to the requierd service name
$termstore = $taxsession.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"] 
$termstore.id

# Get the term set id
$termstoregroup = $termstore.Groups["People"]
# Change to your term set name
$termset = $termstoregroup.TermSets["Department"]
$termset.id
```

This helped me work out the GUIDs for the Department set, and I got the following from the Managed Metadata :

- Managed Metedata Service   : 1856a97abc824059be14f9803d3bc5fd
- People                     : 4ee799fd-a4b4-44f4-b9bd-ce3e6d7d877e
- Department                 : 8ed8c9ea-7052-4c1d-a4d7-b9c10bffea6f

However, whenever I do the following process, my data source always comes up as empty :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here I went with `GetTermSets` but only because it seemed to have the right amount of GUIDs, but I have no idea if this is right! I have not been able to find any good documentation on this ...

[image]

GUIDs here are :

- sspId : Managed Metadata Service GUID
- lcid : United Kingdom LCID
- termId : People GUID
- termSetId : Department GUID

[image]

As you can see, there is no data available :

[image]

And after clicking OK here, I get the message `You must select a repeating group or field`

[image]

There doesn't seem to be any good information on this anywhere but it feels like something that should be relatively simple (considering the data already all exists on a basic web service ... ) really appreciate any help or guidance on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to do this with the following procedure :

**Step 1**
Set up the Data Connection:

`Data -> Data Connections -> Add -> Receive Data -> SOAP Web Service -> http://sitename/_vti_bin/userprofileservice.asmx -> GetUserProfileByName`

Check **Automatically Retrieve Data When the Form is Opened**

---

**Step 2** Create a Hidden Field

Set hidden field's Default Value (in Properties) to:

`Insert Field or Group -> Show Advanced View -> Select GetUserProfileByName datasrouce -> expand dataFields all the way to Values, select Value -> Filter Data -> Add`

**(Property Data)** Name is equal to **(type text)** Department

---

**Step 3** Set up the Rule

`Add Rule (Formatting) -> Condition: (HiddenField Equals IT(or other department name) -> Tick "Hide this Control" (this can also be applied to a group)`