# What is tsns:sspId?

Tags: 2013, infopath, managed-metadata

I am trying to connect my form to SharePoint Metadata, but everything I try is failing.

I am starting to think that I have completely misunderstood what to enter into this window :

[image]

I have been entering the GUID for the top level of my managed metadata service found at `http://sharepoint:35916/_layouts/15/termstoremanager.aspx` but this never seems to work. Can anyone confirm if this is the correct GUID for this parameter?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSPID is the GUID of you Managed Meta Data service. [TaxonomyField.SspId Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfield.sspid(v=office.14).aspx)

You are on the correct place and getting the correct id. Do you have more than 1 MMS service in your farm?

What error you are getting?

Comment: I think I only have this one MMS- I can't see any others under Central Administration. The issue I am getting is that when I try connecting to the data source `http://theoracle/_vti_bin/TaxonomyClientService.asmx` with the above GUID set as the `sspId`, and then the `People` and `Department`  GUIDs for `termId` and `SetId` respectively, I get a message saying `You must select a repeating group or field` when trying to check the data - which I think means that it is only returning 1 item (or less), where I know that `Department` has several entries (I am able to access these through PowerShell)

Comment: I posted another (related) question here  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/180907/how-to-